# VSCode: change font size of menu bars?

Tags: visual-studio-code

A potentially very stupid question, but I'm lost.
How do I change the font size of the **menu bars** (i.e. the labels "File", "Edit", "Selection", "View", ...) including the sidebar explorers, extension menus etc. (i.e. every text that is not the main coding window)?

[image: illustration]

I tried searching the user settings for "font" but I did not see any option specific for the *menu* font size.
I was also not able to find it via Googling.
The version of VSCode I currently have is 1.63.2
I am sure I missed something and apologies in advance for this simple-minded question.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You either need to change the scale of the entire gui, or use custom CSS.

Comment: Thank you! If anyone else is wondering: "CTRL and +" or "CTRL and -" are the standard shortcuts for changing GUI size.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the command palette and run the `View: Zoom In` or `View: Zoom Out` command. The default keybindings for these commands are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

There is also an extension called [Zoom Bar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wraith13.zoombar-vscode) which adds the overall zoom level to the status bar.

This will zoom your main coding windows as well, but you can work against that by adjusting your editor font size in your [JSON settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations):

```json
"editor.fontSize": 14
```

Increase or decrease this depending on your zoom level.

Comment: This solved my specific issue I was having, but not quite the question above - as @HolyBlackCat noted, there currently doesn't seem to be a way to change the menu font size independent of the main font size.

Comment: You're right. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Very useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this exact issue while connecting to an external 4k monitor, the solution I could find relies actually on a windows setting rather than a VS one.
Basically if from the desktop you check your display settings you can adjust as well the resolution and the "scale". In my case I set this to 150%, restarted visual studio and now the menu looks good [windows display settings menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fehj6.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).